# PHP error: Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, oop, overloading

I am trying to build my own session handler for (currently) database storage. When calling it as a normal OOP as shown below in the first example, everything works as intended. Data is stored to the database without any issues.

However when putting it together with the `session_set_save_handler` function to be able to use the `$_SESSION` global variable,
PHP goes bananas like never before and start outputting multiple `Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property` errors.

**What am I doing wrong to cause these horrific errors?**

---

**Working code example:**

```
class session extends sessionBase {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = database::get()->connection();
    }

    function write() {
        // Query to database
    }
}

$session = new session;
session->write(); // Writes to database perfectly
```

**Non-working code example:**

```
class session extends sessionBase {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = database::get()->connection();
    }

    function write() {
        // Query to database
    }
}

$sessions = New session();

session_set_save_handler(
array($sessions,"open"),
array($sessions,"close"),
array($sessions,"read"),
array($sessions,"write"),
array($sessions,"destroy"),
array($sessions,"gc")
);

session_start(); // This is bananas! B-A-N-A-N-A-S!
```

Comment: Does the session class define the functions open, close, read, destroy, and gc?  It doesn't appear to but I thought you might have just left them out of the listing for brevity - if they're actually not there that'd be a problem.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I was just about to write a note that I've left out the _"unrelated"_ functions that is neccessary to get sessions working to make my examples a little easier to read....

Comment: The fault is probably in your unrelated code and has probably nothing to do with the sessions ;)

Comment: @nikic : It won't appear when `session_set_save_handler` isn't set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Indirect modification of overloaded property" is well known in the context of changing arrays returned by `__get`.

I could thus imagine that `read` has to return by reference:

```
public function &read(...) {
    ...
}
```

But following from the fact that this is mentioned nowhere on the whole internet, I assume that the fault lies in someplace different. Probably in some of your "unrelated" code.

Comment: Well, actually all other methods inside the session class are there, but empty and does nothing right now. I've tried to change accordingly to the example of yours and `Notice: Only variable references should be returned by reference` are thrown now also :(

Comment: @Industrial: That may well be the problem. PHP expects these methods to do something. If the all just return `null` things will obviously not work... You should first implement all methods, then go for debugging

Comment: I had done that earlier and then emptied them out with no difference. However I took a longshot after googling and found about the problems with `session_write_close(); ` and after adding this function as the last one in my script - everything works well. Woooo! (Info here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [www.anindya.com](http://www.anindya.com) download *php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip* under "Fixed curl extensions:" and replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder.

Found related issue on: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716,printview,page=1